# Change the coma separator between woocommerce product attributes terms

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, taxonomy-terms

I found an awesome response here that helped me display the product attributes as I wanted on my product archive page here:

[Display specific product attribute in Woocommerce archive pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53697204/display-specific-product-attribute-in-woocommerce-archive-pages)

It is almost perfect despite being several years old. My issue is that I don't see where that array is being looped over in order to change the character joining the attributes. Presumably because it's using a global function. It is currently a ",", but I'd like to use a "/".

Anyone able to help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get "/" as separator instead of "," simply use `str_replace()` function like:

```
echo '<h4>Color:' . str_replace( ',', '/', $product->get_attribute('pa_colors') ) .'</h4>';
```

Comment: perfect! I knew it would be something easy - php isn't my bag, but I'm learning! I was hoping you might be the one to respond! many thanks!